# How to refactor a coroutine and not use Deferred

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to see how I can simply this code to use the latest way, I was wondering if there is a better way to fetch the images, and also not use `Deferred`

```
override suspend fun getImages(): List<Images> = coroutineScope {
    val today = LocalDate.now()
    val deferredImages = mutableListOf<Deferred<Images>>()
    for (i in 0 until numberOfImages) {
        val day = today.minusDays(i.toLong())
        val image = async { api.getImages(day.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)) }
        deferredImages.add(image)
    }
    deferredImages.map { it.await() }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `Deferred`? This is a perfectly valid case for using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```kotlin
override suspend fun getImages(): List<Images> = coroutineScope {
    val today = LocalDate.now()
    List(numberOfImages) { index ->
        val day = today.minusDays(index.toLong())
        async {
            api.getImages(day.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE))
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

The functional approach is so that you don't have to add to the list of `Deferred` manually (but it's not absolutely necessary as @broot pointed out). Also, it technically still is a list of `Deferred` here :)

The important bit is [awaitAll](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html), which fails earlier in case of error in one of the tasks. Using `map { it.await() }` is less efficient because if the last task fails, you will wait for all the others to finish before throwing the exception, instead of cancelling everything and throwing immediately.

Also to clarify a bit what's going on, you can extract pieces in different functions:

```kotlin
override suspend fun getImages(): List<Images> {
    val daysToFetch = windowOfDaysBackFromToday(size = numberOfImages)
    return fetchImages(daysToFetch)
}

private suspend fun fetchImages(daysToFetch: List<LocalDate>) = coroutineScope {
     daysToFetch
         .map { day ->
             async { api.getImages(day.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)) }
         }
         .awaitAll()
 }

/**
 * Returns a window of [size] days, starting from today (included) and going back.
 */
private fun windowOfDaysBackFromToday(size: Int): List<LocalDate> {
    val today = LocalDate.now()
    return List(size) { today.minusDays(it.toLong()) }
}
```

It's longer but the names make it easier to grasp, and also if someone doesn't need to go down a level of abstraction, they can just read `getImages` and stop there.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense